# Need to access adobe pdf viewer without changing Target Platform to x86

Tags: vb.net

Hi I'm using Adobe PDF Viewer in my project to display pdf files in 64bit o.s , It works fine when target platform is set to x86,

But I want the same functionality without changing target platform i.e. adobe pdf reader should work even if we set target platform to ANY CPU as it's the client requirement.Is there any possibility??

Comment: There is no 64-bit version of Adobe Reader.

Comment: oh thanks for response.My requirement can be done by using any other component? I just need to view pdf files without changing target platform, tried webbrowser component but it displays file outside the component.

Comment: If you want to do this in-process I think you'll need to find something else to display the PDFs. Otherwise, you could write the PDF files to disk then use Adobe Reader to read them out of process.